# SQL join in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the following tables:

```
user_friends
>id
>user_id
>friend_id
>status

user_fields
>id
>user_id
>party_status
```

user_friends is a table that list who I am friends. So, I can request a friendship and I would have my id in the user_id column or I can be already a friend of somebody else and my id would be in the friend_id column.

I want to write a query that will return all my friends that have a party_status of 'READY' in the user_fields table and that I am friends with.

Here is what I have thus far but its not getting me what I want and I am having a tough time wrapping my head around it. Any help is appreciated. I am using postgres

```
SELECT * FROM userfriends_friends
        INNER JOIN userapp_userfields ON    (userfriends_friends.friend_id=userapp_userfields.user_id)
        AND (userfriends_friends.friend_id=userapp_userfields.user_id)
        WHERE userfriends_friends.user_id = {user_id}
        OR userfriends_friends.friend_id = {user_id}
        AND userapp_userfields.party_status = 'READY'
        AND userfriends_friends.status = 'APPROVED'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing the OR in parentheses, as in:

```
WHERE (userfriends_friends.user_id = {user_id}
OR userfriends_friends.friend_id = {user_id})
AND userapp_userfields.party_status = 'READY'
AND userfriends_friends.status = 'APPROVED'
```

Otherwise, the engine will bring you every record that has userfriends_friends.user_id = {user_id}, regardless of the other conditions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does work but I ended up having to make two queries because I couldn't match the reverse relationship where friend_id was me and user_id was my friend. The reason why is party_status was returning the party_status for the incorrect person. For me instead of my friend.